# R: how to create median and agreement function for multiple groups

Tags: r, group-by, summary

I have the following data structure:

```
     Player Team Round Question Answer 
 1:      2    1     1        1      1 
 2:      5    1     1        1      1 
 3:      8    1     1        1      1 
 4:      9    1     1        1      1
 5:     10    1     1        1      1
 6:      2    1     1        2      4
 7:      5    1     1        2      5
 8:      8    1     1        2      5 
 9:      9    1     1        2      5
10:     10    1     1        2      5 
11:      2    1     1        4      4 
12:      5    1     1        4      3 
13:      8    1     1        4      4 
14:      9    1     1        4      2 
15:     10    1     1        4      4 
16: ...
```

So there are several players from several team, answering several questions. There are always 2 rounds of games.

What I try to calculate is the medium and the agreement coefficient (see [agrmt package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/agrmt/vignettes/agrmt.pdf)) from the data **by grouping the Team and the Question**.

The result should look like this:

```
      Team Question Median_R1 Agrmt_R1 Median_R2 Agrmt_R2 
 1:      1       1         1        1         1        1 
 2:      1       2         2     0.83         1        1
 3:      ... 
 4:      5      10         4        1         4        1
```

Does someone know if this is possible? I could not find a solution for this. I can solve the median and the agreement coefficient standalone, but not combined?

Every hint is welcome. Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**
The agreement function returns a coefficient between -1 and 1. The values represent.

- 1 represents a full agreement (e.g. if every player answers 5).
- 0 would be, if every player has a different answer.
- -1 would be, if a disagreement exists (some players say answer 1 and others say 5)

[image]

Compared to the median, the agreement functions takes a vector of the frequency vector.

For example, we have the following answers

```
     Player Team Round Question Answer 
 6:      2    1     1        2      4
 7:      5    1     1        2      5
 8:      8    1     1        2      5 
 9:      9    1     1        2      5
10:     10    1     1        2      5
```

The function inputs would look like this:
Median input: `4,5,5,5,5` --> Result: 5
Agreement input: `0,0,0,1,4` --> Result: 0.9

**UPDATE 2: SOLVED**

The calculation of the agreement could be done with the following code:

```
agreement(table(factor(x, levels=1:5)))
```

The final is based on @sandipan implementation. I had to add another sorting step in order to combine the right data.frames:

```
library(agrmt)
df1 <- unique(df[c('Party', 'Question')])
for (df.R in split(df, df$Round)) {
  round <- unique(df.R$Round)
  # get the data.frame of the current Round.
  df2 <- as.data.frame(as.list(aggregate(Answer ~ Party + Question + Round, 
           df.R, FUN = function(x) c(Median = median(x), Agrmt =  agreement(table(factor(x, levels=1:5)))))))
  # sort it and take only the columns of median and agreement
  df3 <- df2[with(df2, order(Party, Question)),][4:5]
  names(df3) <- c(paste('Median_R', round, sep=''), paste('Agrmt_R', round, sep=''))
      df1 <- cbind.data.frame(df1, df3)
}

df1
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Instead of asking us to read through the `agrmt` package Vignette, just tell us what function you want to use for calculating agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three approaches: base R `aggregate`, `dplyr`, and `data.table`.

**With base R `aggregate`:**

```
library(agrmt)

aggregate(Answer ~ Team + Round + Question, data=dat,
          FUN = function(x) {
            c(Median=median(x), 
              Agreement=agreement(table(factor(x, levels=1:5))))
          })
```

> ```
>   Team Round Question Answer.Median Answer.Agreement
> 1    1     1        1           1.0              1.0
> 2    1     1        2           5.0              0.9
> 3    1     1        4           4.0              0.7
> ```

**With `dplyr`:**

```
library(dplyr)

dat.summary = dat %>% group_by(Team, Round, Question) %>%
  summarise(Median=median(Answer),
            Agreement=agreement(table(factor(Answer, levels=1:5))))
```

> ```
>    Team Round Question Median Agreement
> 1     1     1        1      1       1.0
> 2     1     1        2      5       0.9
> 3     1     1        4      4       0.7
> ```

**With `data.table`:**

```
library(data.table)

dat.summary = setDT(dat)[, list(Median=median(Answer), 
                                Agreement=agreement(table(factor(Answer, levels=1:5)))), 
                         by=list(Team, Round, Question)]
```

> ```
>    Team Round Question Median Agreement
> 1:    1     1        1      1       1.0
> 2:    1     1        2      5       0.9
> 3:    1     1        4      4       0.7
> ```

**To get a "wide" data frame as the final output:**

In the examples above, I've left the output in "long" format. If you want to reshape to "wide" format, so that each `Round` get its own set of columns, you can do as follows:

First, let's add a second Round to the sample data by stacking another copy of the sample data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(agrmt)

dat = bind_rows(dat, dat %>% mutate(Round=2))
```

Now calculate the median and agreement with the same code we used before in the `dplyr` example:

```
dat.summary = dat %>% 
  group_by(Team, Round, Question) %>%
  summarise(Median=median(Answer),
            Agreement=agreement(table(factor(Answer, levels=1:5))))
```

Finally, reshape to wide format. This requires first "melting" the data to stack the `Median` and `Agreement` columns into a single column, and then casting to wide format. We also include the second line of code to add "Round" to each `Round` so that we get the column names we want in the wide data frame:

```
dat.summary = dat.summary %>%
  mutate(Round = paste0("Round", Round)) %>% 
  melt(id.var=c("Team","Question","Round")) %>%
  dcast(Team + Question ~ variable + Round, value.var="value")
```

> ```
>   Team Question Median_Round1 Median_Round2 Agreement_Round1 Agreement_Round2
> 1    1        1             1             1              1.0              1.0
> 2    1        2             5             5              0.9              0.9
> 3    1        4             4             4              0.7              0.7
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something as follows, right?

```
df
    Player Team Round Question Answer
1:       2    1     1        1      1
2:       5    1     1        1      1
3:       8    1     1        1      1
4:       9    1     1        1      1
5:      10    1     1        1      1
6:       2    1     1        2      4
7:       5    1     1        2      5
8:       8    1     1        2      5
9:       9    1     1        2      5
10:     10    1     1        2      5
11:      2    1     1        4      4
12:      5    1     1        4      3
13:      8    1     1        4      4
14:      9    1     1        4      2
15:     10    1     1        4      4
16:      2    1     2        1      2
17:      5    1     2        1      3
18:      8    1     2        1      4
19:      2    1     2        2      5
20:      5    1     2        2      3
21:      8    1     2        2      1
22:      2    1     2        4      6
23:      5    1     2        4      1
24:      8    1     2        4      5

library(agrmt)
df1 <- unique(df[c('Team', 'Question')])
for (df.R in split(df, df$Round)) {
  round <- unique(df.R$Round)
  df2 <- as.data.frame(as.list(aggregate(Answer ~ Team + Question + Round, 
           df.R, FUN = function(x) c(Median = median(x), Agrmt =  agreement(x)))))[4:5]
  names(df2) <- c(paste('Median_R', round, sep=''), paste('Agrmt_R', round, sep=''))
  df1 <- cbind.data.frame(df1, df2)
}

df1
    Team Question Median_R1    Agrmt_R1 Median_R2   Agrmt_R2
1:     1        1         1  0.00000000         3  0.2222222
6:     1        2         5  0.04166667         3  0.4444444
11:    1        4         4 -0.05882353         5 -0.5833333
```

Comment: Looks very good. The only problem is that the agreement functions seems not to work corecctly. I assume the problem is that a frequency vector is required (see updated description).